# How to select any random single row from oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I need to select a random single data from oracle db. 'Random' is not any data but any data from a list of data thats retrieved from query. I use below query to list distict data but i need only one to display in response not all of 'em.

```
select distinct name
from billing_account
where user_status = 'Active'
and user_id ='1';
```

This displays all the distinct user names with 'Active' status and Id = '1'. But i need it to display any one random user name. Please help me out!

**Oracle Sql Developer Version 4.0.2.15 and build 15.21**

Comment: Do you really mean "random" or do you simply want to show a single row (even if it will always be the same row, no matter how many times you run the query)? Often this is what people mean, when they say "random". (Obviously, that is a misuse of the word "random" which has a different meaning.)

Comment: Thanks mathguy, but i meant random everytime. Whenever i run the query i should get different data. Below answer solved my question. Please lemme know if you have other means to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM`:

```
select * from (
    select distinct name
    from billing_account
    where user_status = 'Active'
    and user_id ='1'
    order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
)
where rownum = 1;
```

**UPDATE**:

I see that the `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM` is now deprecated. An alternative would be using `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE`:

```
select * from (
    select distinct name
    from billing_account
    where user_status = 'Active'
    and user_id ='1'
    order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
)
where rownum = 1;
```